# Simple group-by for SQL pull

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
Check | Email | Count
Y     | a     |  1
Y     | a     |  1
Y     | b     |  1
N     | c     |  1
N     | d     |  1
```

I want to group it by 'check' and number of counts under each email. So like this:

```
Check | Count #   | Email Addresses
Y     | 1 count   | 1 (refers to email b)
Y     | 2+ counts | 1 (refers to email a)
N     | 1 count   | 2 (refers to email c & d)
N     | 2+ counts | 0 (no emails meet this condition)
```

Every 'check' value is specific to an email

Answer (score 0):

This is most easily done by putting the values in *columns* not *rows*.

But it requires two levels of aggregation:

```
select check, sum(case when cnt = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_1,
       sum(case when cnt >= 2 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2plus
from (select check, email, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by check, email
     ) ce
group by check;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but there might be a cleaner way to get there. I think you need an extra layer of aggregation to pick up the cases where no email meets the condition, assuming you have a record in the source table where the email is null. If there's no record of these cases in the source table, this won't work.

```
select check
      ,count_num
      ,case when email_addresses is null then 0 else email_addresses end as email_addresses
from (
select check, 
       case when count_sum = 1 then 1 when count_sum > 1 then 2+ else 0 end as count_num,
       count(distinct(email)) as email_addresses
group by check, count_num
from (
select check, sum(count) as count_sum, email
from table
group by check, email
)
)
```